# Downloading from Nexus Repository using Python

Tags: python, nexus

I have a task to download some artifacts from Nexus. I am using `nexuscli` library.
The nexus repository structure is very heirarchical.

```
https://localhostABC.de/nexus/#browse/browse
```

will lead to a folder structure as below:

```
release
--de
----Updates
------operating
--------libs
-----------Alib
-------------1.0.0
---------------Alib-1.0.0-zip
```

On the right click of the zip, I get a file path: `de/release/operating/libs/Alib/1.0.0-zip`

When the file path is copied and pasted to another tab in a browser, it directly downloads the zip. The address is https://localhost.de/nexus/repository/release/de/Updates/operating/libs/Alib/1.0.0/Alib-1.0.0-32-bit.zip

To accomodate all of this inside the script for python:

```
import nexuscli.nexus_http

from nexuscli.api.repository.base_models.repository import Repository

nexus_config = nexuscli.nexus_config.NexusConfig(url="https://localhost.de/nexus", username="XXX",password="XXX")

nexus_client = nexuscli.NexusClient(nexus_config)
nexus_http = nexuscli.nexus_http.NexusHttp(nexus_config)

nexus_repository = Repository(name="release", nexus_client=nexus_client, nexus_http=nexus_http)


nexus_repository.download("de/release/operating/libs/Alib/1.0.0-zip",
                          "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Pycharm\\Projects\\Trial", flatten=True)
print("HELLO")
```

It fails and throws an error saying provide creds for Nexus3.

But the credentials are correct as I can download from the browser.

Any suggestions?